# fopen() returns error: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Tags: php, linux

The following code is producing the error I stated in the title:

```
        $authkey = "XXXXXXXXXXX";

    if (!isset($_SESSION["steamid"])) {

        $handle = fopen("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=" . $authkey . "&steamids=" . $uid, "r");

        $content = stream_get_contents($handle);

        $stdclass = json_decode($content);

        //var_dump($stdclass);

        $data = get_object_vars($stdclass->response->players[0]);

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
```

I've read other questions here on stackoverflow with the same problem, but there never was a real solution to it. The code I posted is in an function that is called in some kind of login-process. If I put the code outside an document and open that document with my web-browser, no error comes up. Also, the code is working on my local machine. But on my server the error comes up.

My local machine runs ubuntu 12.04 with php5, my external server ubuntu 8.04 with php5.
allow_url_fopen is "On". Any help would be great.

Comment: You should consider editing out your API key.

Comment: Its just the stupid steam api key, you can request a new one very easily, but I'll edit it out anyways, thanks

Comment: You can try and wrap the authkey with htmlentities()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fopen doesn't allow remote locations to be opened by default. A more stable method would be to use curl:

```
$c = curl_init( sprintf("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=%s&steamids=%s" , $authkey , $uid) );
curl_setopt( $c , CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , true );
$stdClass = json_decode( curl_exec( $c ) );
```

Comment: additionally a 404 can be caused by not parsing the uri properly; maybe the $uid has spaces or so?

Comment: Well, I will try that, but I wonder why it works on my local machine and also works if put I the code outside of the function and open it up with my web-browser.

Comment: Alright, it works with curl, thank you for the fast and correct answer.

Comment: you're welcome, just remember for remote connects file_get_contents and fopen are simply not reliable enough - because each local system might be configured differently.. Additionally curl allows for easy setting of headers and such.